# Trying to remove duplicate elements with the same values that are next to each other in an array (they have to preserve the original order)

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

So). This removes all duplicates. But I cann't figure out the logic for removing duplicates that are next to each other only.

For example:
input:('FFNNbbffnnNN');
output:[F, N, b, f, n, N];

```
var uniqueInOrder = function(iterable){
var newArr =[];
var len = iterable.length;
for(var i = 0; i < len ; i ++){
  if( newArr.indexOf(iterable[i]) === -1){
newArr.push(iterable[i])
  } 
 }
    return newArr;
}
uniqueInOrder('ffssSnnsS');
```

---

Here I tried a little bit.. meh.. begging for tips. Thank you!

```
var uniqueInOrder = function(iterable){
var newArr =[];
var len = iterable.length;
var first = iterable[0];
for(var i = 0; i < len ; i ++){
  if( newArr.indexOf(first) !== newArr.indexOf(first + 1){
newArr.push(iterable[i])
  } 
 }
    return newArr;
}
uniqueInOrder('ffssSnnsS');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var nums = [1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,8];

nums.forEach(function(num,index){
  // Is the current index < the amount of itmes in the array
  // and, if so, is the current item equal to the next item?
  if(index < nums.length && num === nums[index + 1]){
    nums.splice(index,1); // Remove the current item
  }
});

console.log(nums);
```

Comment: The only problem I have with this is that it doesn't take into account more than 2 in a row. For example, try `var nums = [1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,8,8,8];` You'll end up with 2 8s at the end, I'm not sure that's expected.

Comment: His wording was ` removing duplicates that are next to each other only.` which tells me `8,8,8,8` should only end up with one 8, not 2

Answer (score 1):

Better to remove from backward to avoid miss splice when there are more than two duplicate elements after iteration took place:

```js
var nums = [1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,7,8];

for (i=nums.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
    if(i <= nums.length && nums[i] === nums[i - 1]){
    nums.splice(i,1);
  }
}

console.log(nums);
```

Answer (score -1):

I did it like this:

```
function uniqueInOrder(str) {
  const letters = str.split('');

  var lastLetter = null;
  for (let [index,letter] of Object.entries(letters)) {
    if (letter === lastLetter) {
      letters[index] = null;
    } else {
      lastLetter = letter;
    }
  }

  console.log(letters);
  return letters.join('');
}

uniqueInOrder('ffssSnnsS');
```

I use `split` to turn it into an array. I keep track of the most recent previous letter. If the current letter matches, i `null` it in the array, otherwise i just update the `lastLetter` variable.